# Termination of execution of all events

Tags: actionscript-3

I feel like this has probably been asked/answered here, and if so, I apologize for the bandwidth, but I don't see any explanation.
There are many objects, which respond to different events. Is it possible to do so for a certain time all the objects have ceased to respond to all events, and then all events recovered?
Thanks.

Comment: You mean Mouse' events?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep references to objects in the list, for example in the array. In  "a certain time" unsubscribe all objects from the event.

```
 for(var i:int = 0; i < objectsList.length; i++){
 var obj:MyObject = objectsList[i];
 obj.removeEventListener("MY_EVENT", eventHandler);
 }
```

Get a flag (variable) is responsible for your "a certain time" In the event handler check the flag if it is false execute handler code, if true go of it

```
    private function eventHandler(e:Event):void{
    if(flag){
            return;
    }
    //handler code....
    }
```